# Search And retrieve values from database according to checkbox values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a search page which will have the capability to search through the candidates with special skills.

There are multiple check boxes for skills in the fronted. I am storing check boxes values as comma separated values using this function :

HTML

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody><tr>
   <td align="left"><input value="Arts" id="expert_1" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_1"><span>Arts &amp; Performing Arts&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label></td>
       <td align="left"><input value="Environment"  id="expert_4" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_4"><span>Environment&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label></td>
       <td align="left"><input value="Religious" id="expert_7" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_7"><span>Religious</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="left"><input value="Associations" id="expert_2" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_2"><span>Associations</span></label></td>
       <td align="left"><input value="Foundation"  id="expert_5" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_5"><span>Foundation</span></label></td>
       <td align="left"><input value="Social Services"  id="expert_8" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_8"><span>Social Services</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="left"><input value="Education"  id="expert_3" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_3"><span>Education</span></label></td>
       <td align="left"><input value="Health Care"  id="expert_6" name="experts[]" type="checkbox"><label for="expert_6"><span>Health Care</span></label></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody></table>
```

PHP

```
$experts = $_POST['experts'];
$chk = '';
foreach($experts as $expert)  
{  
  $chk .= $expert.",";  
}
```

And I am storing $chk in database.

Now how can I retrieve user from database whose Access field is checked?

Comment: `$ids = join(",", $experts)` and use it in query like: `select * from table where id IN ($ids)`

Comment: try use explode(",",$str)

Comment: Try explode and then check with in_array

Comment: guys he is asking to retrieve them from the DATABASE, not from the PHP string. do you downvote questions without even reading them?

Comment: @FrayneKonok i dont think so it can be done at mysql , instead it have to retrieve the data from db and explode it then check again in .

Comment: @FrayneKonok yes you are right I need to fetch user according to their values checked.

Comment: @FrayneKonok error in mysql syntax!

Comment: `[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE npexp IN Arts' at line 1]`

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0695wo5lf9

Comment: yes I am getting comma list in `$ids`.

Answer (score -1):

Your database structure is not suitable for such a query.

I can't think of a feasible way to achieve that using a SQL query, you should retrieve all records from the database and then select values in php but this is a really bad scenario: php check is much slower than a database one.

Can't you add a boolean field in your database for every checkbox? this would be a much better database structure and it would make your queries much easier

Comment: What do you mean by multiple values? you can add one column for every checkbox and you can add all values you need

Comment: okay than how would I search users according to those values . Suppose I need to find users with skills php & css. And the skills can be too many.

Comment: i mean if users check php and css in search page how would he get accurate results?